# How do I pass Aura v.recordId to a string literal attribute?

Tags: aura, aura-attribute, app-development, bind-variable, omnistudio

I am trying to call an OmniScript from a quick action.

Documentation provides an Aura wrapper for this purpose.

The Omni Script takes recordId as `ContextId`.

Aura passes recordId as `{!v.record Id}`

The prefill attribute follows this pattern:

`Prefill='{"ContextId":"recordId"}'`

Anybody know how to fit `{!v.recordId}` into "recordId" so it still evaluates in the following attribute literal string?

`Attribute='{"Key":"{!v.recordId"}'` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{!` signals the start of an expression, so you would want to always start your expression with that.

However, this will be difficult if not impossible to write as an evaluated expression. It would be better to set this using another attribute. ie:

```
let recordId = cmp.get('v.recordId');
let attribute = '{"Key":"' + recordId +  '"}';
cmp.set('v.attribute',attribute);
```

In the markup, then you can just write:

```
attribute='{!v.attribute}'
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! This was a head banger.